# Jquery Dialog closes after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, modal-dialog

I am using a Jquery dialog popup for users to login to my page. On submit and an invalid username password my dialog closes and when user tries to open the login dialog again he or she will see the error message thrown during login. **How do i stop my jquery dialog to close during a postback ?**

Comment: not unless it's an ajax postback. However, can you post your code so we can see what the issue is?

Comment: true , I didn't use updatepanel properly. Ajax is d way to go :)

Comment: np. do me a favor, i put my answer below. Please accept it, since you cannot do that on the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Just a point of clarification to anyone reading this question - make sure that the UpdatePanel is nested within the jQuery dialog div tags. If it is not then it will be "lost" at the time the dialog is is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not unless it's an ajax postback.